Xcode and Sonoma
Folks, I'm planning to purchase Mac Book Pro M3 Pro but have a few questions about a SCENARIO BASED SITUTATION.

What if I bought MacBook Pro and a couple of months later Apple changes the OS along with Xcode version  and Xcode OS compatibility requirement? (they tend to come up with a new OS every 10 months)

Will it be possible to reload a new OS without loosing my data(draft App) if Apple decides to replace Sonoma?

Will it be possible to update an already downloaded version of Xcode to publish an app to the App Store?


Apple products and software are closely correlated so If I want to publish an app to the App Store I need the latest version of Xcode and to get the latest version of Xcode I need the latest OS.
I don't want to pay a steep price and end up with a product that is not compatible with Apple requirement to publish an app. Please Advise
This is a general question which didn't require a technical solution

Not sure this really qualifies as a programming question… Sure, you’ll be able to update the OS version and the Xcode version on a new laptop without loss of data.  Eventually your hardware won’t be able to continue to be updated, but expect that to be a matter of years, not months.
